# Poping in animation with fixed postion changing with browser using MooTools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mootools

I need to do with an animation that is intially the image will be on full screen whenver i click on the screen it will popin an go to a div. for this i haved used te following code.

```
<div class="header_relative">
<header id="cover_photo_header" class="large">
<img></img>
 </header>
 </div>
```

styles:

```
<style>
header_relative
{
position:relative
}
  header, a, img{
  transition: all 2s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s;
 -webkit-transition: all 2s; 
 -o-transition: all 2s; 
}
header.large
{
 position: fixed;
  top: 0;
    left: 0; 
   width:100%;
  height:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 19;

}
header.small
{
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 19;
 }
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
 window.addEvent('click', function(){
$('global_content').getElement('header.large').style.width = '770px';
$('global_content').getElement('header.large').style.height = '300px';
   $('global_content').getElement('header.large').style.margin = 'auto';
 $('global_content').getElement('header.large').style.top = '-294px';
 $('global_content').getElement('header.large').style.left = '29.1%';
setTimeout(function(){
//do what you need here
$('global_content').getElement('header').removeClass("large").addClass("small");
func, delay
}, 2000);
});
```

But he animation is changing on left.Can you guys help me howto come out of this

Comment: I see a missing dot (`.`) in your `header_relative` CSS class. Also a `func, delay` part in the code I don't know what you mean. Can you __[adapt this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZy22/)__ to your code so we can help you better?

Comment: (.) i have set it in my code and func delay also we can remove them,the image should move up in the centre of the screen and last 10px of the image should be seen,by that my next functionality is when we click n that image(10px).the the image should popout at the centre of the screen

Comment: Ramz, can you adapt the jsFiddle I posted above? if you click on the image what do you expect to happen?